# Q. Rails undefined method `nome_completo' for #<Room:0x0000000ed6d478>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails4

Meu Controller:

```
class RoomsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_room, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def nome_completo
    "#{title}, #{location}"
  end


  # GET /rooms
  # GET /rooms.json
  def index
    @rooms = Room.all
  end

  # GET /rooms/1
  # GET /rooms/1.json
  def show
  end


  # GET /rooms/new
  def new
    @room = Room.new
  end

  # GET /rooms/1/edit
  def edit
  end
......
end
```

Minha View:

```
<h1>Quartos recém postados</h1>
<ul>
    <% @rooms.each do |room| %>
    <li><%= link_to room.nome_completo , room %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

> O erro exibido:
>       undefined method `nome_completo' for #Room:0x0000000ed6d478

Como vocês podem ver o método já está definido no controller, e minha view consegue chamar varios métodos da controller Room exceto aqueles que eu defini.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não pode definir métodos em seu *controller* que são responsabilidades de seu modelo. Baseando-se na ideia do [MVC](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/MVC), seu *controller* apenas é um "encaminhador" de requisições. Logo, você deve delegar essa responsabilidade para seu modelo.

Para tanto, adicione o método em seu modelo Room

```
def nome_completo
  "#{title}, #{location}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver, o problema é que o método deveria estar definido no model, e não no controller. Caso fosse no controller o erro que eu receberia seria

> ## RoomController:0x0000000ed6d478

ao invés de

> ## Room:0x0000000ed6d478